# How to create streams dynamically based on values in one attribute of the event?

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to create multiple streams dynamically. For example.

```
{'event_type': 'temperature',
 'users' : ['john', 'gary'],
 'data': {'type': 'temperature', 
 'DeviceID': 'bcd', 'temperature': '45',
 'timestamp': '2019-03-22T12:32:02.208223Z'
         }
}
```

Possible values for `type` are `['temperature','geolocation,'pressure']`.
The desired output is one stream per user and one stream per user-type combination

```
The following queries are what we expect (Code that creates the following)

select x,y,z from stream
insert into john

select x,y,z from stream
insert into gary

select x,y,z from stream
insert into john_temperature

select x,y,z from stream
insert into gary_temperature

etc.
```

1. Is this possible to do in wso2?

I tried https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP4xx/Complex+JSON+Processing
 for complex json processing, but the @source syntax is not mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in Siddhi. In Siddhi, Streams are predefined and cannot be created based on event attributes.